# How to load data from file without repeating records

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, mysql-workbench

I have a text file which contains comma separated fields. The records in the file can be duplicated. However, when I insert them into the database, I want to insert the first occurrence of the record and ignore any repeated ones (based on the first field value which should be unique).

Here is my statement which causes errors due to repeated values of the first filed which I am marking it unique.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.txt'
INTO TABLE `scheme`.`mytable` fields terminated BY ',';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned to be easy. Just use `IGNORE` and MySQL will ignore repeated occurrence.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/myfile.txt'
IGNORE INTO TABLE `scheme`.`mytable` fields terminated BY ',';
```

However, this will IGNORE every other error. So it should be used with cautious.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loaddata to load row into into a 'temp' table, then

```
INSERT INTO targetTable (firstField, ...set of columns...)  
  SELECT DISTINCT firstField, ...set of columns... 
    FROM temp 
    WHERE firstField NOT IN (SELECT firstField FROM target);
```

It needs : firstField -> set of colums (functional dependency)

Or you can use INSERT with IGNORE option (no error when duplicates) :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO targetTable (firstField, ...set of columns...)
 SELECT DISTINCT firstField, ...set of columns... 
    FROM temp;
```

or as table schema are the same :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO targetTable 
   SELECT * 
    FROM temp;
```

Comment: Thanks. Even without ignore. Everything will be inserted correctly and duplicate will not. For some reason, I thought the whole insert was not done due to the errors as I used to flush all the data if I encountered any error.

Comment: So you can get duplicates in your target table, INSERT + SELECT DISTINCT will only eliminate duplicates (DISTINCT) from the temp table.

Comment: I meant, by using `LOAD DATA` exactly as in my question. It completes the insert for the distinct records. The duplicated ones do not get inserted. This seems easier than two steps solutions.